# Drupal Views: can I use only date and not time when using a date filter?

Tags: drupal-views

Stupid question but I'm still getting into the Drupal side of Civi.

I've made a View to show the participants of events in different programme areas. One of the filters is the start date of the event, that's exposed to allow them to search for specific dates.

However, the filter is using ISO8601 format in that it has HH:MM:SS and using the filter requires users to know the both the date and the time when the event started. Is there a value type that I can use instead so that it only searches for the date and not the time as well?

Comment: what happens if you only enter the YY:MM:DD part in the filter - do you not get results for that whole day?

Comment: I think you mean YYYY-MM-DD. Worth trying, but I suspect it won't match unless you've got a fancy date filter that knows about the datetime format. It's challenging in views because it handles dates and times stored in various kinds of formats.

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM Event start end dates are stored like this:

2021-11-03 13:00:00

i.e. the mysql datetime format.

That field gets exposed into the Drupal views magic and then it's up to views to do stuff with it.

For what you want, you'll either have to find a fancy views filter that can filter datetimes by day, or you may be able to use a hard-coded beginning and end of date times, e.g.

greater than 2021-11-03 00:00:00
and less than or equal to 2021-11-03 23:59:59

Your options will depend on which version of Drupal you're using.